# executing a shell-script through makefile

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu-12.04, make, makefile, deb

i am trying to create a .deb file that first installs the
dependency that is stored in the some folder, for that i have created a shell
script. My issue is executing the shell script through
make file my make file format to call a shell script is like this:

```
$(shell PATH="$(../)" "./something.sh")
```

but when i do a fakeroot debian/rules clean, it throws an
error:

```
./something.sh: 3: ./something.sh: sh: not found
./something.sh: 4: ./something.sh: make: not found
./something.sh: 5: ./something.sh: make: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting PATH to "" you even commands in /usr/bin can't be found.

I assume you want to add .. to PATH. What you want is:

```
$(shell PATH="$(PATH):.." ./something.sh)
```

Assuming you are doing something with the output of something.sh, if not then:

```
PATH=$(PATH):.. ./something.sh
```

Is all that is required.